# Spin operators in relativistic calculations (Dirac theory)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-spin, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

In non-relativistic quantum mechanics, the spin operators associated with a particle of spin 1/2 are proportional to the $2\times 2$ Pauli matrices
$$
\widehat{\sigma}_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\qquad 
\widehat{\sigma}_y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \qquad 
\widehat{\sigma}_z= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
From the article *Dynamics of the relativistic electron spin in an electromagnetic field* (https://doi.org/10.1088/1361-648X/aba675), I can deduce that the relativistic Dirac spin operators for a particle with spin 1/2 are proportional to the three matrices
$$
\widehat{\Sigma}_x = \begin{pmatrix} \widehat{\sigma}_x & 0_2 \\ 0_2 & \widehat{\sigma}_x
\end{pmatrix},\qquad 
\widehat{\Sigma}_y = \begin{pmatrix} \widehat{\sigma}_y & 0_2 \\ 0_2 & \widehat{\sigma}_y
\end{pmatrix},\qquad 
\widehat{\Sigma}_z = \begin{pmatrix} \widehat{\sigma}_z & 0_2 \\ 0_2 & \widehat{\sigma}_z
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $0_2$ is the $2\times 2$ zero-matrix. My question is the following: **How do the matrix representations of $\widehat{\Sigma}_{x,y,z}$ change when we consider a triplet state** (or higher spins). In non-relativistic calculations, the matrix representations of the spin operators of a triplet are $3\times 3$ matrices. However, I have not yet seen relativistic eigenstates with more than four components, so I am not sure how the spin operators change in relativistic theory.

Comment: Tensoring. Look at spin 3/2 gravitinos $\psi_\mu$, Rarita-Schwinger spinor-vector fields.